# Vue js- How to duplicate array when a spesific key selected

Tags: arrays, vue.js, for-loop

I want to storage customers contact infos. I am getting an array from server that includes type of contacts;

```
0: {type: "mobile", icon: "fas fa-mobile"}
1: {type: "home", icon: "fas fa-phone-alt"}
2: {type: "firm", icon: "fas fa-phone-alt"}
3: {type: "email", icon: "far fa-envelope"}
4: {type: "instagram", icon: "fab fa-instagram"}
5: {type: "tiktok", icon: "fab fa-tiktok"}
6: {type: "youtube", icon: "fab fa-youtube"}
```

I do have a for loop so i can show them as inputs. What i want to do is, user must be able to add more than one contact type. Like, 2 or 3 phone number at once.

```
[ { "value": { "label": "Mobile", "icon": "fas fa-mobile", "value": mobile, "inputValue": "(584)" } } ]
```

I have a variable holding datas like that.

What is the best way to do that. You can even just type answer any idea would be nice. Thanks

Comment: if you have an existing Vue component for this, I suggest adding that source code to your question, both the template and the JavaScript.